# What is the process for closing/merging Stack Exchange sites if they eventually fail?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

There is a really nice process for the creation of new Stack Exchange sites (in my opinion), but is there a process for closing or merging sites if the community around a sites starts dying?

I do not think that will happen in a year, but let's say that SharePoint is discontinued 5 years from now and in 10 there are few new Q&A's and few views. Will it be merged with Stack Overflow again?

The question might be relevant if some of the new sites do not take off after the beta.

Comment: The Gadgets site (which I can't find the Area 51 link for right now) failed and it's good questions were split between Gaming, Apple and Android. There is a precedent.

Comment: Also Guitars was apparently merged into Music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few (very few, but > 0) failed SE2 sites. When that happens, we've made a data dump of the site available for downloading.

Examples:

- [Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence)
- [Atheism](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2732/atheism)
- [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets)
- [How Things Work](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15025)